# Função Jquery .load porém dentro do documento

Tags: javascript

Quero utilizar algo similar a função do `.load`, porém quero pegar uma `div` dentro do meu próprio documento, o qual vou deixar ela oculta com `display : none`, como conseguiria fazer essa chamada? 
Tentei:

```
if(escolha == "predefinido")
{
    $("#filtro").load("#predefinido1");
}
```

Porém não tive resultado, qual seria o correto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está passando um elemento como parâmetro no load?
Desculpas, mas creio que isso não irá surtir efeitos, o load poderá ser usado para fazer uma consulta ao servidor través de um ajax no parâmetro e até uma url que possa disponibilizar uma carga útil de dados, mas isso não aplicabilidade em um elemento em seu document.
Poderia conseguir melhor resultado esclarecendo o que pretende fazer e o que espera como resposta para a sua necessidade, aí sim quem sabe poderá receber uma orientação que realmente seja viável e seja possível a aplicabilidade dela.

**EDITADO:**

veja esse exemplo se lhe atende...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="conteudo">
    <h2>CONTEÚDO PRINCIPAL...</h2>
  </div>

  <button data-tipo="1" onclick="mudaConteudo(this)">MUDAR CONTEÚDO</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function mudaConteudo(obj) {
      // if para verificar o tipo do botão
      if ($(obj).attr("data-tipo") == 1) {
        // se for 1 o data-tipo ele faz as seguintes alterações...
        $("#conteudo").html("<h2>CONTEÚDO ALTERADO...</h2>"); // muda o html da div conteúdo
        $(obj).html("DESFAZER CONTEÚDO"); // Muda o html do botão
        $(obj).attr("data-tipo", 2); // Muda o valor do atributo data-tipo do botão
      } else {
        // se for diferente de 1 o data-tipo ele faz as seguintes alterações...
        $("#conteudo").html("<h2>CONTEÚDO PRINCIPAL...</h2>"); // muda o html da div conteúdo
        $(obj).html("MUDAR CONTEÚDO"); // Muda o html do botão
        $(obj).attr("data-tipo", 1); // Muda o valor do atributo data-tipo do botão
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Uma pequena correção no seu código do git na função..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#predefinido").click(function(){ 
         $("#predefinido").html("#predefinido1") }); });

</script>
```

obtive esse resultado... 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

era isso mesmo que pretendia fazer?

**Complemento da Solução**

```
var escolha = $(this).val();
var predefinido1 = " copie o html que vc quer no arquirvo todasEscolhas.html e cole aqui"; 
var naopredefinido = " copie o html que vc quer no arquirvo todasEscolhas.html e cole aqui"; 
var contato = " copie o html que vc quer no arquirvo todasEscolhas.html e cole aqui"; 
if(escolha == "predefinido")
{
  $("#div-unica").html(predefinido1);
}
else if(escolha == "naopredefinido")
{
  $("#div-unica").load(naopredefinido);
}
else if(escolha == "contato")
{
  $("#div-unica").load(contato);
}
// NOTA: div-unica é a criação de apenas uma div que vai se alterando conforme o botão clicado e escrevendo o html da opção desejada
// como os conteúdos são sobrescrito, não tem necessidade de ter mais que um elemento para servir como quadro para esse conteúdos
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92278/discussion-on-answer-by-junior-silva-funcao-jquery-load-porem-dentro-do-documen)

Comment: @Bacco seria realmente viável em diversas situações a utilização do chat, mas essa funcionalidade não me aparece como opção de escolha, então deveria eu de encerrar outras dias tentativas de ajudar quem buscou a comunidade devido a essa questão :/

Comment: A sala foi criada especificamente para este caso, e pode ser acessada pelo link do comentário acima. [(é o mesmo que esse aqui)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92278/discussion-on-answer-by-junior-silva-funcao-jquery-load-porem-dentro-do-documen)

Answer (score 0):

Seria mais fácil você usar uma combinação de jQuery e css.
Você pode esconder #predefinido1 com display:none no seu css e usar o jquery para mostra lá.

```js
$('button.btn').click( function(){
  $('#predefinido1').toggle();
   $('#conteudo').toggle();
});
$('button.mostra').click( function(){
  $('#predefinido1').slideToggle();
   $('#conteudo').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#predefinido1 {
  display: none;
  padding:40px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
#conteudo{
  padding:40px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="predefinido1">
  Contédo secundário
  <button class="btn">Mostra Div</button>
  <button class="mostra">Slide Div</button>
</div>
<div id="conteudo">
  Conteudo principal
   <button class="btn">Mostra Div</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No caso preciso que até o botão some.... dando assim espaço para outros botões, vai ter um botão de voltar, mas não é o caso
Essa função daria certo?

Comment: Editei o código acima. Você só precisa organizar dentro de cada div o conteudo que quer que apareça ou suma.